# PHP DomDocument class doesn't exist

Tags: php, linux, domdocument, redhat, php-extension

I was trying to use the class `DomDocument`in my php code on redhat linux server, but when I have tried the following code:

```
echo "class_exists(\"DomDocument\") = ".(class_exists("DomDocument")?" EXISTS ":" NOT EXISTS ")."<br>";
```

it prints:

```
class_exists("DomDocument") = NOT EXISTS
```

after a small search I found that the extension `php-xml` should be installed, but the class still not exist, and the following is a snippet from `php -i` result:

```
dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.6.26
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled
```

What is still missing to make this `DomDocument` class work?

Comment: The name is `DOMDocument`. Case is significant.

Comment: Yep, the name is `DOMDocument` but it worked for me with lowercase as well.

Umm... could you check your php.ini and see if it contains the `extension=dom.so` line?

Also both libxml and DOM has to be enabled but they are by default so that shouldn't be a problem if you haven't messed with the ini before and your `php -i`  confirms that.

Comment: @PockeTiger, Thank you I have edited the php.ini file and added `extension=dom.so` to extensions part, and then I have restarted the service `httpd` and it is  working now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help there :3

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can accept it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check your php.ini and see if it contains the `extension=dom.so` line?

Also both libxml and DOM has to be enabled but they are by default so that shouldn't be a problem if you haven't messed with the ini before and your `php -i` confirms that.